# Error connecting with GidSignInButton from Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I have added a GIDSIGNINBUTTON programatically, and added a target to it, to authenticate after the Firebase instructions. The problem is that the popup web page appears and it lets me login, but there I catch an error Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-5 "The user canceled the sign-in flow." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The user canceled the sign-in flow.} And as well
Warning] Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<SFAuthenticationViewController: 0x1060b6200>)
Thank in advance for the help

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @SamH. yes I have found check for what event the button targets the method, It should be .touchUpInside, if you do for allEvents It will trigger twice the gidsigninbutton opening one after the other which is not possible which results in the error above. Hope this solves your problem.